# Change images folder for slider automatically depending on page loaded on Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, slider, joomla2.5

I'm doing a site and i have the following issue:

I have to show a lot of products, and in each page for each product i have an slider, this slider must have diferent images for every product. The thing is, as i'm using an slider component/module for joomla 2.5, i need to duplicate it for every product (at least for the little i know of joomla).

There is no other way to chance the images for the slider automatically, without duplicaiting the module/component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use plugins to create image sliders easily inside articles.**[Nice Slide Show](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/slideshow/image-mootools-slideshow/14970)** is a paid extension that will serve your purpose.

The [Simple Image Slider](http://www.dynatec.at/joomla-extensions-modules-plugins-components/simple-image-slider-sis-plugin-for-joomla-1-5) is a free plugin but couldn't find its 2.5 version.

Also check this plugin:[Sliding Image Links](http://falsinsoft-joomla.blogspot.in/2011/10/sliding-image-links.html)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks man, i've just figured out how to use the following Slider: http://www.bretteleben.de/ . It's working just fine! Thanks for your help anyways!